# Low-resolution photo in camera roll when saved with Photos framework

Tags: ios, photosframework

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:saveImage]; 
    if (_collection) {
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:_collection];
        [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[[assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset]]];
    }
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating asset: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

I use the code above, and I got a strange photo in camera roll like photo 1.
[image]

but when I open the saved photo with VSCO or snapseed, I can get the normal version which was the right one I saved.

Is this a bug of apple's camera roll?

[image]

It's very strange that it looks good If I save inputData directly to photo library, but after adding metadata,the photo in system photo app looks unclear.

```
-(NSData*)getDataOfImage:(UIImage *)image
                 metaData:(NSDictionary *)metaData
{
    NSData *inputData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0);

    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) inputData,nil);
    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData new];
    CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(imageSource);
    CGImageDestinationRef imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef) outputData, UTI, 1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource (imageDestination, imageSource, 0, (__bridge CFMutableDictionaryRef)metaData);
    BOOL result = CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination);
    if (result == YES) {
        NSLog(@"success: save MetaData");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"failed :save MetaData ");
    }
    CFRelease(imageSource);
    CFRelease(UTI);
    CFRelease(imageDestination);
    return outputData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachesDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//NSString *temporaryPath = [cachesDir stringByAppendingString:@"temp"];
NSString *temporaryPath = [cachesDir stringByAppendingString:@"temp.jpg"];
```

Very weird...after adding an extension type, it's resolution become normal saving with photos.framework PHAssetChangeRequest.
Seems default saving extension type is PNG ...not JPG...

Answer (score 0):

By default PHPhotoLibrary saves image as jpeg with compression coefficient 0.8.
For get better quality create image yourself (e.g. with coefficient 0.95) and use creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL:) instead of creationRequestForAsset(from:).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: What you can't reproduce? I think it's not documented, I found this experimentally and it works for me.